# Inverse for the term "refinement”

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, computing

In computer science there is a term "refinement".
Refinement is a hierarchical relationship between two concepts. If B refines A, then the requirements of B are a superset of the requirements of A. Thus, the set of abstractions that model B are a subset of those that model A, i.e., every B is an A.

At the same time there is a term "lifting". It stands for finding a concept with least requirements to fit a particular algorithm.

The question is how to describe A in terms of B if B is a refinement of "A". Similar to ancestor vs. descendant.

My guess is "A is a lifting of B". But I'm not sure I can use "a lifting" in English.

Comment: The origin on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355303/what-is-the-inverse-notion-of-refinement

Comment: Those who do understand the terms, understand that this is Too Localized.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact context, it may be appropriate to write *A relaxes B* or *A is a relaxation of B* to mean *B refines A* or *B is a refinement of A*.

Comment: Yes, this is an explanation, but I am seeking for a word that refers not to the properties of concepts but to concepts directly.

Comment: thanks! This makes sense. What do you think of my suggestion?

Comment: "A is a lifting of B"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Generic Programming Glossary](http://www.generic-programming.org/about/glossary.php):

> **Refinement** is a hierarchical relationship between two concepts. If B
>   refines A, then the requirements of B are a superset of the
>   requirements of A. Thus, the set of abstractions that *model* B are a
>   subset of those that model A, i.e., every B is an A.

And in turn:

> A **model** is a type or set of types that meets the requirements of a
>   concept. An integer pointer is a model of the Input Iterator concept.
>   *"Model" can also be used as a verb to describe the relationship between a type or set of types and a concept*, e.g., an adjacency list
>   models the Graph concept.

So, according to standard usage, A *models* B.

As for *lifting*:

> **Lifting** is the process by which the *differences among multiple, concrete implementations of the same algorithm are abstracted away*,
>   producing a generic algorithm.

I don't think it's quite correct to say that the inverse of *refinement* is *lifting*, since lifting *concrete implementations* of A and B produces some new generic entity C.

So, as far as there is an inverse of *refinement*, it's *model*.

> A *models* B; B is a *refinement* of A.

Comment: **"Models"** refers to *types* and not to *concepts*, so it is not the right term to use in the context of this question. In some more details a model is a specific implementation that realizes the requirements of the concept.

Comment: @Dror Read the definition of _refinement_ again; the distinction you're trying to make isn't explicit in that definition, as I read it.

Comment: I still think (and as far as I know this is also the case) *refinement* refers to a relation between concepts, and *model* refers to  the properties of types. Rereading the definition that you cite seems to support this understanding of mine.

Comment: @Gnawme, Dror is right.